# TTcpServer remote connection to service

Tags: delphi, networking, delphi-7

i need win XP service with TTcpServer.

application was created by "File->New->Other->ServiceApplication"

TTcpServer.localport := 33000

server registered with exename.exe /install

everything looks good, even `netstat -a` shows that port 33000 - LISTENING

but i can`t access that port from outside of this machine. only local.

and when i make the standard application with same params - all ok.
[image: TTcpServer config]

**EDIT1**
TTcpServe.OnAccept =

```
procedure TFlexorXL.tcpServerAccept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
  var str: string;
begin
 if ClientSocket.Connect then
 begin
    str := ClientSocket.Receiveln;

  ClientSocket.Sendln('test');
               //ClientSocket.Disconnect;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What happens when a client tries to connect to the service? Is there is error? On the client side or the server side? What is the actual error? You need to be more specific.

Comment: no errors. just timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP/IP works just fine in a service (I use it all the time), so you are likely just misusing the `TTcpServer` component (which is possible, because it is a horribly written component).

If the `TTcpServer.LocalHost` property is blank then the socket will bind to all available local IPv4 addresses, otherwise it will bind only to the particular IPv4 address that you specify (netstat will show you the actual IP that the server is actually bound to).  That is the IP that you must have clients connect to.  In the case of `0.0.0.0`, you can connect to any IP that belongs to the server's machine.

With that said, in order to actually accept clients, you must either:

1. set the `TTcpServer.BlockMode` property to `bmThreadBlocking`. The server will then use an internal worker thread to accept connections, and each client will run in its own worker thread.  However, you must perform all of your client-related logic inside of the `TTcpServer.OnAccept` event, because a client will be disconnected immediately after that event handler exits.
2. for any other value of `BlockMode`, you must call `TTcpServer.Accept()` yourself, such as in a timer or thread.  If you call the overloaded version of `Accept()` that has no parameters, you must perform all of your client-related logic inside of the `TTcpServer.OnAccept` event, because the client will be disconnected immediately after that event handler exits.  If you call the other overloaded version of `Accept()` that returns a `TCustomIpClient` object, then you control the lifetime of that object and can use it however you need.

With that said, if you are doing all of that, and still having problems, then you need to provide more information about your actual `TTcpServer` setup, show some actual `TTcpServer` code, etc.  As it currently stands, you have not provides enough details to diagnose your problem.

Comment: TTcpServer.LocalHost set to local area network ip (192.168.3.222). and as i said above if the TTcpServer on TForm - all works fine. if i put it on TService ... problems

Comment: @Subdigger: then clients can only connect to `192.168.3.222`. I assure you, TCP/IP itself works fine in a service, so this is going to come down to being an issue with your code interacting with `TTcpServer` the wrong way in a service environment, but you did not show any of that code yet. In any case, `TTcpServer` is a really bad component in general (in fact, the entire `Sockets` unit is bad), so you really should ditch it. Either use the VCL's original `TServerSocket` component, write your own Winsock code from scratch, or switch to a third-party socket library like Indy, ICS, or Synapse.

Comment: ... with TServerSocket same thing. if i use it in standard application - all goes correct (receive & send). if i move it to service it do not responding to remote ip

Comment: Then I would suggest you double check your firewall/router and make sure they are allowing inbound traffic to reach your service.

Comment: any advice for how i can do it in winXP. i looked to the policies loolks like nothing needed...

Comment: + can the problem is that i used virtual machine (virtualBox)?

Comment: It depends on the VM's network configuration. There are plenty of online tutorials for working with virtual machine networking.